# How to mask two images using Imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, minimagick

I have two images to be done. How to mask the first image to the second image as background?
[here's the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOmcN.png)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a black and white mask of your first image and use that to cut out the second.
Check out this link: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/ and have a go.

Comment: hey sorry I am totally noob about image processing stuff. This is what I've done so far:
`convert image1.png  -alpha extract _image1.png`
then
`convert _image1.png -size 300x500 tile:image2.png -compose Multiply -composite result.png`. But the background of the result is black, how to change it to transparent? @Bonzo

Comment: I've found the solution. Here it is http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#badge_mask_paint